# Using adapterPosition within a private function in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter

I'm currently trying to access

```
adapterPosition
```

within a private function however, I am presented with the following error

```
unresolved reference: adapterPosition
```

It cannot find a declaration to go to.

when I use adapterPosition outside this private function I do not have this error.

```
  private fun speakCurrentValue() {


    val position = adapterPosition
    val currentItem = exampleList[position]
    lateinit var tts: TextToSpeech

    tts.speak(
        currentItem.percent.toString(),
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
        null,
        ""
    )

    handler.postDelayed(Runnable{speakCurrentValue()}, delayMs)
}
```

any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adapterPosition` will be an `Int`. You can pass it to your `private function` as an argument.

```
 private fun speakCurrentValue(position: Int) {

    val currentItem = exampleList[position]
    lateinit var tts: TextToSpeech

    tts.speak(
        currentItem.percent.toString(),
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
        null,
        ""
    )

    handler.postDelayed(Runnable{speakCurrentValue()}, delayMs)
}
```